# Addin folder to command line Java execution

Tags: java

Hope there is a simple answer for this.  We have an old SWING application that is launched from the command line.  It depends on a set of libraries that are located in a folder C:\lib.
What is the correct syntax from loading C:\lib to the classpath.  Something like this?

```
java -jar myapplicaiton.jar -CLASSPATH="C:\lib"
```

This seems to result in an Exception relating to being unable to see the libraries

Comment: "java -cp="C:\lib" -jar myapplicaiton.jar" would be more accurate, but could be overridden if the jar contains a manifest file with a class-path entry, also, I'd probably include the environment variable %classpath%, but that's me

Comment: Thank you - yes was thinking of the environment!